# Rename Folders After Copy

Tags: powershell, copy, administrator

I'm having problems after a folder is copied to a different location, I need to rename the folders in the directory to remove ".deploy" from the end, but I get the following error below. I have Googled around for PowerShell admin permissions, but cannot seem to find a 'catch-all' for my scenario.

```
Get-Content : Access to the path 'C:\OldUserBackup\a.deploy' is denied.
At C:\PSScripts\DesktopSwap\TestMergeDir.ps1:28 char:14
+             (Get-Content $file.PSPath) |
+              ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : PermissionDenied: (C:\OldUserBackup\a.deploy:String) [Get-Content], UnauthorizedAccessException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : GetContentReaderUnauthorizedAccessError,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetContentCommand
```

Here is what I have:

```
$UserName = [Environment]::UserName
$CurrUser = [Environment]::UserName + '.deploy'
$OldUserDir = 'C:\OldUserBackup'
$CurrDate = Get-Date -format G

$PathExist = Test-Path $OldUserDir

if ($PathExist -eq $true) {
    #Copy Desktop, Downloads, Favorites, Documents, Music, Pictures, Videos
    Copy-Item -Path $OldUserDir -Destination C:\Users\$UserName\Desktop\CopyTest -Recurse -Force

    $configFiles = Get-ChildItem $OldUserDir *.deploy -rec
    foreach ($file in $configFiles) {
        (Get-Content $file.PSPath) |
            Foreach-Object { $_ -replace ".deploy", "" } |
            Set-Content $file.PSPath
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the `-Directory` switch on the [Get-ChildItem](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=113308) cmdlet to only get directories. Then use the [Rename-Item](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=113382) cmdlet to rename the folders. I use the `-replace` function with a simple `regex` to get the new folder name:

```
$deployFolders = Get-ChildItem $OldUserDir *.deploy -rec -Directory
$deployFolders | Foreach { 
    $_ | Rename-Item -NewName ($_.Name -replace ('\.deploy$') )
}
```

---

You don't even have to use the `Foreach-Object` cmdlet ([Thanks to AnsgarWiechers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37837411/rename-folders-after-copy/37837771?noredirect=1#comment63136906_37837771)):

```
Get-ChildItem $OldUserDir *.deploy -rec -Directory | 
    Rename-Item -NewName { $_.Name -replace ('\.deploy$') }
```

Comment: Useless use of `ForEach-Object`. `Rename-Item` can read from the pipeline, so you can directly feed it the output of `Get-ChildItem`.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers But how will you access the old name to replace `.deploy`?

Comment: `... | Rename-Item -NewName { $_.Name -replace '\.deploy$' }` (note the curly braces).

Comment: @MartinBrandl Thank you guys. Saved me a lot of head ache.  About ready for live testing :D